# How to remove optional fields from registration form

Tags: joomla, joomla3.0

In Joomla 3.8.3 registration form, how do I remove the optional fields?
[image]

Note: The User-Plugin is disabled.

Comment: This does not look like profile field. There should be another extension that is adding these fields. Try filtering plugins of User group and see if fields are coming from any of those fields. Also, make sure this is Joomla default registration, not any custom extension.

Comment: I discovered it was an extension (EasyDiscuss)... thanks for helping!